# Как передать значение переменной из кода на го в хранимую процедуру?

Tags: sql, postgresql, golang, plpgsql

Код на го:

```
   func main() {
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s 
    dbname=%s sslmode=disable",host, port, user, password, dbname)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Successfully connected to data base!\n\n\n")
    fmt.Printf("Enter id: ")
    var i int
    _, _ = fmt.Scanf("%d", &i)
    //rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id,surname FROM mytable WHERE id=$1",i)
    rows,err := db.Query("SELECT mypr()")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var s myStruct
    for rows.Next(){
        err:= rows.Scan(&s.id,&s.surname)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    fmt.Printf("|id|   surname  |\n-----------------\n")
    fmt.Printf ("|%2d| %9s  |",s.id,s.surname)
}
```

Код процедуры:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mypr() 
 RETURNS TABLE (id integer, surname character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    begin
        return query (select * from mytable where id=i);
        return;
    end
$function$
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не помню `go`, так что если предположить, что закомментированная строка

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id,surname FROM mytable WHERE id=$1",i)
```

корректна, то правильный эквивалент с вызовом функции будет:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id,surname FROM mypr($1)",i)
```

И соответствующая хранимая функция:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mypr(i integer) 
 RETURNS TABLE (id integer, surname character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    begin
        return query select id, surname from mytable where id = i;
        return;
    end
$function$
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваша процедура должна принимать параметр:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mypr(userid INTEGER)
-- …
```

А запрос со стороны го должен выглядеть так:

```golang
rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT * FROM mypr($1)`, 1)
// …
```